# Learn how information is transmitted

Tags: electromagnetic

Maybe this is not the right place to ask this, it is so, please tell and I will delete this question.

I want to learn how information is transmitted using radio and TV. I want to learn that because I want to know if it is possible to use another electromagnetic wave, like visible light, to send information.

What do you recommend me to start learning how information is transmitted using radio or TV?

Comment: I would try google but be prepared, there is a lot to understand and a lot of it is quite technical and mathematical.

Answer (score 2):

*I want to know if it is possible to use another electromagnetic wave, like visible light, to send information.*

Yes it is, you undoubtedly already know that WiFi exists, there's a similar (but still somewhat experimental) technique called [LiFi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li-Fi)

It is **no surprise** that light can be used to transfer information. Light and radio waves are both EM (Electro Magnetic) waves. Light is "just" at a higher frequency and our eyes are sensitive to it.

Also, fibre-optic cables have been in use for a long time and also use light for transporting information.

How to learn: just start reading some books and browse online. Also youtube might have some videos explaining things. Just follow your interest. This is a broad subject and how deep you want to go depends on your interests and what you need. To **really** understand how for example Television works (and be able to explain it properly) could take **years**.

Comment: My curiosity comes from SETI project: they don't find anything!!! Maybe aliens are using another EM wave to transfer information. I really interested in how information can be send in a EM wave. Thanks!!

Comment: *I really interested in how information can be send in a EM wave.* Most basic way: on/off so I can send Morse code or binary data. More complex: I **modulate** the (phase, frequency of the) EM wave and that carries the information. SETI: **even if** there are aliens sending signals, their signals would need to arrive here **now**, not 1 million years ago or in 1 million years, also, the EM waves we can receive are only from a **very small part** of the universe. All-in-all: the chance to receive some signal is very, very small indeed.

Comment: IrDA is worth mentioning re: information transfer via light. Your remote control uses it!

Answer (score 1):

Eventhough this is not the right place to ask this question, nevertheless there is no single right place to ask it anyway :-)

This is because, the TV and radio devices are at the interconnection of multidues of technologies (electronics, electromagnetics, communications, multimedia, signal processing, etc.), hence no single one of them can yield the full answer.

Information transmission, apparently involves two entities: first is the **information** and the second is the **transmission**.

Engineering treatment of information is mathematically presented within the **Information Theory** branches of communication system theory of electrical engineering.

This mathematical treatment involves the **quantification** of information (in terms of Entropy bits) through a probabilitistic / statistical **characterisation** (in terms of probability density and distribution functions) of the **sources** that generate them. This could be analog or digital.

This stage involves **source coding** (representation of information in terms of discrete entities - codewords) which turns into a data **compression** scheme to reduce the number of bits (average bitrate) necessary to represent a given source.

This stage also involves **channel coding** which increases the bitrate to make them more robust against channel transmission errors; aka error correction coding.

This stage also includes **cryptology** to make the transmitted data secure, if needed.

Then the **transmission** should be analysed:

The mathematical treatment of transmission is handled in the **modulation** theory of communications systems which deals with various methods of moduation and demodulation structures to transmit a given message signal under least amount of bandwidth, least available power or least error or least distortion conditions. This again can be analog such as AM/DSB/DSB-SC/SSB/VSB/FM/PM/QAM or digital such as ASK/PSK/FSK/QAM etc.

All these are mathematical treatments. However the radio and TV equipments are physical devices and thus require electrical and electronic components to realize those operations.

The most notable of such physical hardware will be the **antennas** to propagate and receive RF (radio frequency) waves that carry the modulated message signals.

Once these waves are adequately captured, next hardware would be the **tuner** which would isolate a selected communication channel (simply the TV-radio channel) from the rest by tuning into it using PLL (phase locked loop) , SAW (surface acoustic wave) devices and IF, LF **mixers**.

Mixers are oscillators that multiply a given signal to change their base frequencies. From RF to IF from IF to LF. Or backwards at the broadcasting transmitters.

Finally digital decoding of the source data and various tasks are handled at the decoder ICs... Note that today's practice is digital video and audio.

So yes, you can use different means and techniques to **carry** the information contained in the source message signal.